# can't set first flex tile in place on mobile view

Tags: html, css, flexbox

the first tile goes to the right while it has to be in the middle like the rest of the tiles. as you can find in my fiddle for example.

```
.tiles {
    display: flex;
    flex-wrap: wrap ;
    justify-content: space-between;

}
    .tile1 {
        flex: 0 1 80%;
        height: 20vh;
        background: #fff;
        position: relative;
        background: url("../images/h2.jpg");
        background-size: cover;

    }
```

https://jsfiddle.net/0vw5e58o/

Comment: your html is wrong .. use dev tools to inspect elements. You have a strange `a` tag

Comment: what do you mean it's wrong?@TemaniAfif

Comment: you have a strange link tag ... and check your fiddle at the end, it seems you are missing an openinng div

Comment: it's for the scripts on my site I obviously added just a part of the web, this is why there is an extra closing tag in the end. @TemaniAfif

Answer (score 0, accepted):

its better to try center instead of space-between

```
justify-content: center;
```